# Oracle Convert Char to Date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following date in oracle table:

'2017-08-01 00:00:00,000000000'

I want to convert this to date which I am using the following but I don't know how to deal with zeroes?!

```
.
.
.
T.EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
between to_date('2017-08-01  00:00:00,000000000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
and to_date('2017-08-10 00:00:00,000000000', 'yyyy-mm-dd  hh:mi:ss');
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle dates do not support milliseconds.  Assuming your `EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` column is a date, then the following comparison is the best you can do:

```
T.EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-08-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') AND
        TO_DATE('2017-08-10 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss');
```

If you wanted to convert a text string with milliseconds to a timestamp, you could use something like this:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP ('2017-08-01 00:00:00,000000000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss,ff')
```

Comment: `,` vs `.` separators in your to_timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this values in not a date but a timestamp so I would use following conversion:

```
select to_timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00,000000000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss,ff6')
from dual;
```

Technically you can have non zeros after comma, so If you want to get correct but not truncated value use timestamp date type.